# How to remove the "selected" Attribute and move it to another option using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, attributes, cypress

I have tried:

```
cy.get(`div[class="input-group input-group-sm"] select[name="activeStatus"]`).find(":selected").invoke("removeAttr", "selected")
```

which doesn't work as I have hoped, but it's been the closest to it I think. Anyone have any tips? I want to move the "Selected" attribute from Active, to Cancelled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're halfway there, the removal part works. To add `selected` to `Cancelled`, invoke `attr`

```js
// remove
cy.get('select')
  .find(':selected')
  .should('contain', 'Active')
  .invoke('removeAttr', 'selected')

// add
cy.get('select')
  .find('option')
  .contains('Cancelled')
  .invoke('attr', 'selected', true)

//confirm
cy.get('select')
  .find(':selected')
  .should('contain', 'Cancelled')
```

---

This gives you

```js
<option selected="selected">Cancelled</option>
```

If you prefer

```js
<option selected>Cancelled</option>
```

use this instead

```js
// add
cy.get('select')
  .find('option')
  .contains('Cancelled')
  .then($el => $el[0].setAttribute('selected', ''))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! ```cy.get('select').find('option').contains('Cancelled').then($el => $el[0].setAttribute('selected', ''))
        cy.get('select').find('option').contains('Active').invoke('removeAttr', 'selected') ```was what worked for me